# How to distinguish between electron and google chrome environment

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, electron

For example the following code:

```
<div id="app">
  <wv></wv>
</div>
<script>
  if (inCrm()) {
    Vue.component("wv", {
      template: `<iframe></iframe>`
    })
  } else if (inElectron()) {
    Vue.component("wv", {
      template: `<webview></webview>`
    }) 
  }
  new Vue({el: "#app"})
</script>
```

I hope to debug in chrome and run in electron, how to distinguish between the two at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution in [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2288)

use following code:

```
window && window.process && window.process.type
```